# Eclipse IDE for Java Dev on ubuntu 10.04 not working

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, java-7, ubuntu-10.04, minecraft

I have downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java Developers on my ubuntu 10.04 LTS image so that i can do some modding for Minecraft, sadly when i tried to run eclipse I got this error

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/sheldon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/sheldon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/sheldon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/sheldon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/sheldon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 194800f
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/sheldon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

I have JDK7 x86 installed as well as wine and the latest version of IcedTea (java for ubuntu).
In the past i have found that programs request to much RAM / Video RAM and so they don't run, although eclipse doesn't seem to: -Xms40m -Xmx512m (I think the max is -Xmx512M -Xms512M on my computer)

Comment: try to launch eclipse in terminal, what's the error output in terminal?

Comment: `cd <eclipse folder>; ./eclipse`

Comment: Same error as before but in the terminal it spat out this:

Comment: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: I take it it should say 32 not 64? is it trying to run a 64bit version of eclipse of Java?

Comment: You downloaded a 32bit eclipse. Are you using 64bit JRE? If that, you should download a 64bit eclipse instead.

Comment: I have a 32 bit system so i download the 32 bit version of java

Comment: Could you try to run `java -version`?

Comment: `java version "1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment  (IcedTea 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need wine or IcedTea.  If you get the JRE from SUN and the IDE from Eclipse.org you should be able to navigate to the Eclipse directory and ./eclipse

JRE:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Eclipse:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1

Comment: I use wine and IcedTea for other things, just thought I would put it there in case that is the problem with my install of Eclipse

Comment: Do I need JDK, JRE or Java SE?

Comment: JRE.  I believe Eclipse will fetch it but I have always installed the JRE before installing Eclipse. Let me know how it works out for you

Comment: That might be the problem. I currently have JDK installed not JRE, although I thought IcedTea was JRE?

Comment: IcedTea is code name of Java 7. JDK always contains JRE by default.